# Implementing Nokia Here SDK in Android

Tags: android, sdk

I want to develop an app in android using 'here sdk' but i'm unable to find any libraries or files to include in my android project. I have searched over here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple.html    but still no luck.

Can anyone guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I've found is here: https://github.com/haroldcalayan/SmartPlaces/find/master. You can download the sdk files individually (here-sdk.jar and here-sdk.jar.proprties).

However I have no idea what version of the SDK is this.

Judging by the apparent lack of support for HERE SDK online, I would guess this project is either abandoned by Nokia or have evolved into an online service. I would reconsider my options here.

Comment: Thanks.  My codes compiled perfectly without showing any errors but it shows "Unfortunately, app has been stopped" message.

Comment: This is a crash. Please open a new question with the stacktrace. This will get the attention of people with experience in HERE SDK.

Also - if you like the answer please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download their SDK from this link [HERE](https://developer.here.com/applications/create/sign-in?planId=10138434&subplanId=10138435&platformId=10138442&keepState=true)

If you want to try their TBT Navigation, download their Premium SDK.